# how to extract parameters value from short dynamic link in firebase?

Tags: android

My apps sending a short dynamic link as email like:

**https://jEVV7.app.goo.gl/YyHEf?userId=KERJdner4554_aemrnmJe2_WKrmsaf&session=LKE8eEehjr_erjlek34JHFDZcxfberejEJredfMDFnm**

where i have added the deep link **https://www.example.com/cart** with dynamic link with as short dynamic link.

on Clicking the email it opens linked activity but it cannot retrieve paramters value (here value of userId and session) by deepLinkUri.getQueryParameter("userId"). What am i doing wrong here?? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters should be part of the deep link and not the dynamic link.

When you are creating the dynamic link, use `https://jEVV7.app.goo.gl/YyHEf` as dynamic url and `https://www.example.com/cart?userId=KERJdner4554_aemrnmJe2_WKrmsaf&session=LKE8eEehjr_erjlek34JHFDZcxfberejEJredfMDFnm` as deep link.

Now you will be able to retrieve parameter values.

Android code to create a dynamic link

```
Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = 
FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/cart?userId=KERJdner4554_aemrnmJe2_WKrmsaf&session=LKE8eEehjr_erjlek34JHFDZcxfberejEJredfMDFnm"))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("jEVV7.app.goo.gl")
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Short link created
                        Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                    }
                }


            }).addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    //handle failure
                }
            });
```